# ListFragment won't refresh

Tags: android, contextmenu, fragment

here my code inside my ListFragment (I am using a context menu):

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
            .getMenuInfo();
    Log.d(TAG, "onContextItemSelected clicked");
    long id = info.id;
    Log.d(TAG, "list id " + id);

    int menuItemIndex = item.getItemId();
    Log.d(TAG, "menuItemIndex " + menuItemIndex);
    if (menuItemIndex == 0) {
        try {
            plantManager.deletePlantRelation(id);
            CharSequence text = getActivity().getString(
                    R.string.info_could_delete_plant);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), text,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            loader = getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            CharSequence text = getActivity().getString(
                    R.string.info_could_not_delete_plant);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), text,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The method is executed, and I get the Toast-Message - but the List won't refresh.

Looking forward your help.

Thanks in advance!

update:

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {

        return new CursorLoader(getActivity()) {
            @Override
            public Cursor loadInBackground() {
                myCursor = plantManager.fetchPlantRelations();
                return myCursor;
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: I think we are going to need to see the code for onCreateLoader.  If deletePlantRelation actually removes the item from the underlying dataset, you shouldn't have to both restart the loader *and* notifyDataSetChanged...

Comment: yes the dataset is removed from the database - I have checked it

Comment: well, that's not a huge help: what does fetchPlantRelations do?  The point here, though, is that none of this should be necessary.  See the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Not only should you not need to do both a reset on the LoaderManager *and* a notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter, you really shouldn't have to do *either*.  The right way to do this is to make sure that the cursor that is returned by fetchPlantRelations() has been registered for notifications on a particular URI.  If you then make is so that changes to the underlying dataset (like those cause by deletePlantRelation) notify that URI, the rest will happen completely automatically.  Check out the code here:

https://github.com/marakana/yamba/blob/yambaII/YambaService/src/com/marakana/android/yamba/svc/data/YambaProvider.java

Look, especially, at lines 182 and 242.  That' all there is to it.